# Keras Model showing no signs of improvement

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning

I'm having issues with the learning ability of my model and I feel like I'm missing something obvious. As shown in the video, the snake learns to find the first reward but improvement stops after that. What am I missing? I've tried altering the parameters and adding dropout but it seems to have very little effect.

Another minor issue I'm having is the speed that tesseract reads the score. I've added several config settings but the effects are minor. The current reading takes about .5 seconds which is horrible for fast paced games.

My model and parameters:

```
#Parameters
keys = [W,A,S,D]
action_size = len(keys)
memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
gamma = 0.95
epsilon = 1.0
epsilon_min = 0.01
epsilon_decay = 0.995
learning_rate = 0.001

#Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(80, input_dim=80, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(80, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(action_size, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate))
```

My question is how to increase the "accuracy" of the model. 
All suggestions are welcome.

Here is the video demo:
[Snake Video](https://youtu.be/gSWF92kemOo)

Github link to the full code - https://github.com/ttorkar/snake

Comment: an interesting idea, what has inspired you too do it? Any examples? :)

Comment: I would add a small reward for not hitting the border, + you need more time for learning...

Comment: Hi Paddy, I was a little inspired by sentdex's GTA model. I was disappointed in the Gym module because it's not as practical as I'd like. I've added a reward to increase time and trained for 700+ episodes but it can't seem to get past the first piece of food.

Comment: I just checked your keras model, did you try a different number of layers? I would also increase in dense layer (128->64->32). Also, 700 epochs are not enough, people training models for weeks... Anyway, before you start a such long train, could you please tell me why are you using linear activation function for the last layer and MSE as a loss function?  As, I understood the output of your model is the probability of "using" a button. If so, the softmax and categorical_crossentropy would fit you better...

Comment: any updates with the model?

Comment: Hi Paddy, unfortunately I've had some computer issues and haven't been able to run it for an extended period of time. Do you have an estimate of the amount of iterations that would be required to learn to "play" a game of this complexity?